# Python3.4 HTTP connection using ip, port, path

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

im trying to establish a HTTP connection but getting the error:

> "http.client.InvalidURL: numeric port: '80/test/path'

Code:

```
Import http.client

self.conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("192.168.1.1:80/test/path") #"[ip]/[path],[port] does'nt work either

# some post and put requests
```

working Code:

```
Import requests

requests.post('192.168.1.1:80/test/path',data='testdata')
```

How can I establish a HTTP Connection by using ip, port and path?

Comment: I don't think you can: That "path" is a property of the request, not the connection. IP (host) and port (if non-standard) should be sufficient.

Comment: like @DaSourcerer said: first you establish the connection to (ip, port), then you use `.request(method, path)` on the opened connection. See https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request . Or just use requests which is way easier than http.client